# Second 3D View FOV ultra wide

Tags: 3d-view

So I opened up another 3D view and for some reason the second 3d view is super wide and when I make more 3D view windows it's still ultra wide and I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the properties panel, press 'n' to bring that up and go to "view" and you can see the lens view in mm, the default is 35mm, so you can set it to that.